# Signatures Invalid and Problem with MergeList error

Tags: unity, 14.04, gnupg, signature

So, whenever I try to update repos recently (via apt-get), I get something like this:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 6AF0E1940624A220 Launchpad PPA for TualatriX
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 5A9A06AEF9CB8DB0 Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu Wine Team
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_libreoffice_libreoffice-4-3_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

When I disable all the ppas, these errors disappeared. Is this a problem with the launchpad servers or is the problem within my configuration or something? I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Well, by digging around a bit (looking at the problematic files apt-get referred to in the errors) I found that apt-get downloaded interstitial pages placed by my ISP thinking it's a signature or package list, and ends up failing to recognize them. I'm not sure why it only happens with the ppas though, and why this only began yesterday.